# How can I display current user posts?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display the posts of a current user. The Post ID and the User ID are the same. An error occurs when I get to the list view code specifically (

```
snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document))
```

and I get this error:

> The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' . Try importing the library that defines 'doc', correcting the name to the name of an existinggetter, or defining a getter or field name 'docs'.

What do I do from here please? Or what did I do wrong?
My code:

```
class MyRidesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyRidesScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyRidesScreen> createState() => _MyRidesScreenState();
}

class _MyRidesScreenState extends State<MyRidesScreen> {
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myPosts = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection('ADS')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: myPosts,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
                child: Text(
              'Error occured',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ));
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: Text('No requests yet'));
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: Text("Loading"));
          }

          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(),
              );
            }),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Ads Collection

User Collection

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong is that you're trying to call the `docs` on a single document. You can only get docs of a collection/query, not on another single doc since this is not logical.

```
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myPosts = FirebaseFirestore
  .instance
  .collection('ADS')
  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
  .snapshots();  // this is a stream of single document snapshots, not a whole collection so you can call docs.
```

you should call `docs` on a `CollectionReference` or a `Query` only.

in the other side, if you only want to show that document which exists in the "ADS" collection, then you should be using it directly in the Flutter widget, not trying to call `docs` on it:

instead of this:

```
      return ListView(
        children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(),
          );
```

you should use this:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> documentData =
              snapshot.data.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(),
          );
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm more or less like a beginner. Can u rewrite this code for me as u meant. Just that I didn't really get it.

Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myPosts = FirebaseFirestore
  .instance
  .collection('ADS')
  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
  .snapshots();

Comment: If it's possible can you write the whole code. I'm a bit lost